# My website is displaying weird characters instead of letters

Tags: html, css, web

I have made a simple Arabic landing page using Bootstrap, Everything was working fine and when I open my local HTML file on the browser it seams okay. So I have hosted the website to the this domain https://play-gulf.fun/ , it was fine for 3 days but when I went to check it now I found that no letters are displayed and instead there are weird letters appearing on my website
[image: screenshot]
This is the head tag of my html

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/Gulf-White-Icon.png" />

    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cairo:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&family=Readex+Pro:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

    <title>PlayGulf</title>
  </head>
```

You can find the rest of the code if you inspect the website.

Comment: please share your html code

Comment: please read how to ask question in stack overflow link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: can you share code ? which creates issue means displays weird words(add html code here)

Comment: @FTW I don't know really, can you check for me please? https://play-gulf.fun/

Comment: @ParthRaval I have edited the question, now it have the code

Comment: The <meta charset="UTF-8" /> in the posted code doesn't seem present in the website you linked

Comment: this is blank html...add body section here....

Comment: @AbdelrahmanAhmed This is a language label problem. The code on the second line caused this problem:
<br>
*lang="en"*

You are supposed to change it into:
<br>
*lang="ar"*
<br>
Because the language is Arabic and if you told the browser it is English, the browser will parsing wrong encoding format.
I tested the code, it works.

For more languages' code, you can visit [This website][1]


  [1]: https://www.dofactory.com/html/language-codes

Comment: @HanHan The language tag does _not_ cause such behaviour! It's plainly an encoding issue; the website simply does not declare its encoding properly.

Comment: @deceze Oh, I see. And what's the meaning of  language tag, I used to think it is  *lang="en"*

Comment: @Han It’s a hint what language the letters represent. E.g. is the word “mist” English or German? It can also be a hint what font to render characters in, e.g. Chinese and Japanese will use different fonts for the same Chinese character. It does *not* preclude using a completely different language than the one specified though.